# pass parameter in std::async or in std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

Here is my class

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void foo(const std::string&);
};

int main()
{
    Foo* pFoo = new Foo();
    std::string str = "string";
    //If I want to start an async task, I could do this:
    std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&Foo::foo, pFoo,  std::placeholders::_1), str);
    //or do this:
    std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&Foo::foo, pFoo, str));
}
```

So what's the difference?Which way is safer to use?

Comment: Why not use a lambda? `[&str, pFoo] {pFoo->foo(str);}`

Comment: Why use `bind` *at all*?

Comment: What did your studies of the documentation reveal?

Comment: I don't know. There is a situation why I asked this question is: When you computer is put into sleep, and your application happens to run at "std::async...." there, what will happen when the computer wakes up"? Will it crash?since the variable str no longer exists?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::future<void> t = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::foo, pFoo, str);
```

`std::bind` is basically obsolete at this point.  Use lambdas in the rare case that you even need lambdas.

`async` is one of many `std` functions that treat member functions much like standard functions, but with `this` as a bonus first argument.  So no binding or lambda or what have you required.

Always store the result.  If on msvc, always `wait`, as msvc has non-compliant `future`.  The standard dictates that the destructor of `std::future` blocks if it came from an asynchronous async.  MSVC violates that.  As standard violations have a habit of being reverted, by always `wait`ing you prevent a surprise if and when they produce a compliant compiler.

Comment: If I wait, I will block the current thread, right? So if I don't wanna block the current thread, I have to create another thread to run "wait". Then my question is why I need to call std::async at first place? I can just create a thread and run the task in that thread directly.

Comment: @YaoDing The purpose of std::future is to request a result (at some point of time, even void). If you do not need/want that use a std::thread

Comment: @YaoDing You `wait` when the main thread needs to know the other task is finished.  If you never need to know if the other task is finished, clearly not doing that task is sufficient, so don't bother doing the task, as your code accepts it never finishing!  Efficiency!  ;)  But seriously, you need to at least know the other task is finished *by the time the program is finished* or you could have some dangling thread out there being summarily terminated by the end of `main` (or some other, undefined by the standard, result). You can wait for a message "back" saying "done", and only then `wait`.